# array manipulation in node js and lodash

Tags: node.js, lodash

I have two arrays 
  `typeArr = [1010111,23342344]`
 `infoArr={'name':'jon,'age':25}`

**I am expecting following**

```
[{'name:'jone','age':25,'type':1010111,'default':'ok'},{'name:'jone','age':25,'type':23342344,'default':'nok'}]
```

Code :

```
updaterecord(infoArr,type)
{
  infoArr.type=type;
  response = calculate(age);
  if(response)
     infoArr.default = 'ok';
 else 
    infoArr.default = 'nok';
  return infoArr;
}
createRecord(infoArr,typeArr)
{
   var data = _.map(typeArr, type => {
       return updaterecord(infoArr,type);
    });
  return (data);
}

var myData = createRecord(infoArr,typeArr);
```

I am getting

```
[{'name:'jone,'age':25.'type':23342344,'default':nok},{'name:'jone,'age':25.'type':23342344,'default':nok}]
```

with some reason the last record updates the previous one. I have tried generating array using index var but not sure what's wrong it keep overriding the previous item.

how can I resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the entire `infoArr` array to your `updaterecord()` function, but `updaterecord()` looks like it's expecting a single object. As a result it is adding those properties to the array rather than individual *members* of the array.

It's not really clear what is supposed to happen because `typeArr` has two elements and `infoArr` has one. Do you want to add another to `infoArr` or should `infoArr` have the same number of elements as `typeArr`.

Assuming it should have the same number you would need to use the index the `_map` gives you to send each item from `infoArr`:

```
function createRecord(infoArr,typeArr) {
   var data = _.map(typeArr, (type, i) => {
        // use infoArr[i] to send one element
       return updaterecord(infoArr[i],type);
    });
  return (data);
}
```

---

#### Edit:

I'm not sure how you are calculating `default` since it's different in your expected output, but based on one number. To get an array of objects based on `infoArray` you need to copy the object and add the additional properties the you want. `Object.assign()` is good for this:

```
let typeArr = [1010111,23342344]
let infoArr={'name':'jon','age':25}

function updaterecord(infoArr,type){
    var obj = Object.assign({}, infoArr)
    return Object.assign(obj, {
        type: type,
        default: infoArr.age > 25 ? 'ok' : 'nok' //or however your figuring this out
    })
}
function createRecord(infoArr,typeArr) {
    return _.map(typeArr, type => updaterecord(infoArr,type));
}
```

Result:

```
[ { name: 'jon', age: 25, type: 1010111, default: 'nok' },
  { name: 'jon', age: 25, type: 23342344, default: 'nok' } ]
```

Comment: I want to create an array with two item [name,age,type,default]  but value for type and default are populated based on infoArr

Comment: So you want an array with 2 items and "jone" is both items? You want a copy of the 'jone' item?

Comment: yes jone,age same for both record but type and default fields different

Comment: You added  `calculate(age)` but no definition? And how can you expect 'default' to be 'nok' in one and 'ok' in the other if the age is the same??